# Redis SORT BY using Lua Script

Tags: c#, redis

i am trying to implement this command using LUA
`SORT gnm:dev:Conductor:ProjectID BY gnm:dev:Master:Project:*->CoreName ALPHA LIMIT 0 10`

This works fine in console.

I am getting a syntax error running this using LUA in C# (at using :*->. The commented line works fine).

```
LuaScript prepared = null;
prepared = LuaScript.Prepare($@"return redis.pcall('SORT', @key1,'BY', @key2, ':*->', @fieldName,'ALPHA','LIMIT',@min,@max)");
//prepared = LuaScript.Prepare($@"return redis.pcall('SORT', @key1, 'BY',@key2, 'ALPHA','LIMIT',@min,@max)");
   var list = client.GetDatabase().ScriptEvaluate(prepared, new
       {
           key1 = (RedisKey)new CacheKey("Conductor", "ProjectID").ToString(),
           key2 = (RedisKey)new CacheKey("Master", "Project").ToString(),
           fieldName = "CoreName",
           min = 0,
           max = 15
            });
```